# Not able to light up keyboard LED using outb() call

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, device-driver, hardware-port

I am trying to light up the keyboard LED in Linux with the following program (found this on internet) but nothing seems to happen. Am I missing anything?

```
/* sample.c: very simple example of port I/O
 *
 * This code does nothing useful, just a port write, a pause,
 * and a port read. Compile with `gcc -O2 -o example example.c',
 * and run as root with `./example'.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/io.h>

#define BASEPORT 0x0060 /* lp1 */

int main()
{
        /* Get access to the ports */
        if (ioperm(BASEPORT, 3, 1)) {perror("ioperm"); exit(1);}

        /* Set the data signals (D0-7) of the port to all low (0) */
        outb(0xED, BASEPORT);

        /* Sleep for a while (100 ms) */
        usleep(1000);
        printf("\n here ");
        outb(0x07, BASEPORT);
        usleep(1000);

        /* We don't need the ports anymore */
        if (ioperm(BASEPORT, 3, 0)) {perror("ioperm"); exit(1);}
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious error in that code. However, I tried on my machine and the caps lock led is turned on by that code (but not on my keyboard but only on the laptop leds).

Comment: Is this a USB keyboard? This port is for old ps/2 style keyboards, USB keyboards work completely differently of course. However the old interface is somewhat emulated in some conditions... I don't know enough about this, but someone might...

Comment: Here some information: http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes.html#toc11. Perhaps it will be useful.

Comment: When i do /proc/ioports, i see keyboard port as 0x60-0x64 and 0x60 is for accepting commands. First i tried this on ubuntu running on virtual box on my laptop, it didn't work and then also on standalone systems, result is same. Neither my key was light nor caps lock was on. This is USB keryboard.

Comment: USB keyboards usually have their commands dispatched through the HID protocol. This might not be the right way to do it.